# Want to inline SVG ICON and text on same line html/css/bootstrap

Tags: html, css, svg, bootstrap-5

I want to inline SVG image/icon and text on same line but its not working. Below is code

```css
.row.justtify-content-left.icon1 {
  padding-left: 260px;
  padding-top: 36px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row justtify-content-left icon1">
  <div class="col-md-4 icon1">
    <img src="images/icon/graph-up.svg" width="30px" class="img-fluid icon1" alt="">
    <h5>INVESTMENT PLANNING</h5>
    <p>This handout will help you understand how paragraphs.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please correct your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go...

**You need to "separate" the image and the text into two columns inside the same row.**

You do this with classes **`col-1`** and **`col-11`**. As stated on Bootstrap's official website: *There are 12 template columns available per row, allowing you to create different combinations of elements that span any number of columns. Column classes indicate the number of template columns to span (e.g., col-4 spans four).*

So, **1+11=12**.

Note: I changed your image with an image of a giraffe so you can see the result.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>

  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' integrity='sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl' crossorigin='anonymous'>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="row justtify-content-left icon1">
    <div class="col-1 icon1">
      <img src="https://animals.sandiegozoo.org/sites/default/files/2016-11/animals_hero_giraffe_1_0.jpg" width="30px" class="img-fluid icon1" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-11 icon1">
      <h5>INVESTMENT PLANNING</h5>
      <p>This handout will help you understand how paragraphs.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```